# how to get the count of items in two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to get the count of items in one of the dimensions of a 2 dim array.

For example, a simplistic version of my array looks like this:

```
my_array(0)(1) = "a"
my_array(0)(2) = "b"
my_array(0)(3) = "c"
```

I'm trying to find out the count of items in my_array(0). But of course you can't do "my_array(0).count", so trying "my_array.count" simply gives me 1. So how do I get the count of the items in the second dimension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array.getlength):

```
Dim dimLength = my_Array.GetLength(1)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I guess, my problem is more complicated than I thought. My array starts out being defined as an ArrayList because I read in some data from a db and then add that to my arraylist with my_array.add(list of items). Then I convert my arraylist to an array using my_array.toArray() If I try to use GetLength, it tells me Getlength is not a member of arraylist. So I guess it still sees my array as defined (arraylist) and it isn't really being converted.

Comment: Why are you using arrays at all? Use a `List(Of YourClass)` instead.

Comment: I use an arraylist so I can add other lists to it easily and then I can later address them as my_array(0)(i) and go through them easily.

Comment: I would suggest to use a strongly typed generic `List(Of T)` where `T` is a class that you have to create with meaningful propertynames and appropriate types. That helps to reduce complexity and improves maintainability considerably. There's no need to use `ArrayList` anymore and you should really get familiar with classes and OOP in general instead of using multi dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for the count of every element in your array you might want to consider using the Sum function:

```
Dim totalcount As Integer = m_array.Sum(Function(x) x.Count)
```